# Read temperature from nRF51 SENSOR PRO via bluetooth

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to read temperature from bluetooth "nRF51 sensor pro". It is pretty different from "nrf51 sensor" I used till now. It has different temperature chip - Bosch BMP280 so also UUID's and decoding of temperature is different
this is the sensor:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32970609595.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.295f4c4d3HfllW
Unfortunatelly I do not have any documentation. It is even not possible to google uuids which sends this sensor.
I guess these are correct ID's to use to receive temperature values, but I have no idea how to decode received temperature

```
    GATT_SERVICE = "6a800001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e" in old sensor it was  "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"

    GATT_TEMP_CHARACTERISTICS = "6a80b280-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e" in old version it was "6e400005-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
    SENSOR_DESCRIPTOR = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
```

Anybody is able to read the temperature succesfully ?